# Serilog not logging

Tags: c#, serilog-sinks-file

I have the following config

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureSiteLogging(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(@"D:\inetpub\logs"))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\inetpub\logs");
    }

    services.AddLogging(builder =>
    {

        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            var loggerConfiguration = new LoggerConfiguration()
                                        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                                        .WriteTo.File(@"D:\inetpub\logs\shop.txt"
                                                    , rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day
                                                    , encoding: System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                                                    , retainedFileCountLimit: 2
                                                    , restrictedToMinimumLevel: Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information
                                                    );

            builder.AddSerilog(loggerConfiguration.CreateLogger());

        });
    });
    return services;
}
```

in the site program file:

```
Log.Information("Web Service Running");
await app.RunAsync();
Log.Information("Web Service Stopped");
Log.CloseAndFlush();
```

the issue is that I see no log on disk, why isn't it flushing? These are my NuGet packages

```
<PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.11.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="6.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.AppSettings" Version="2.2.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
```

Comment: SeriLog should have a settings "Buffered", try to set it to false.

Comment: @PaoloIommarini, thanks for the suggestion, I updated the configuration setting the buffered value to false... no changes, nothing written

Answer (score 3):

I found what I missed, not sure if it's a feature but you have to assign the logger to **Serilog.Log.Logger**, the call to builder.AddSerilog() doesn't do that step...

Here is my working solution

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureSiteLogging(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(@"D:\InetPub\logs"))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\InetPub\logs");
    }
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .MinimumLevel.Information()
                    .WriteTo.File(@"D:\InetPub\logs\shop.txt"
                                , rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day
                                , encoding: System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                                , retainedFileCountLimit: 2
                                , flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
                                , shared: true
                                ).CreateLogger();

    services.AddLogging(builder =>
    {
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddSerilog(Log.Logger);
        });
    });
    return services;
}
```